# Is there a distribution such that a sum of its samples creates the uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, discrete-data

Say I sample $N$ numbers from a mystery discrete distribution and add them all together. My goal is for the sum of these random variables to be uniformly distributed from $[a,b]$ and thus the distribution is paramaterized by $(N, a, b)$. Does such a distribution exist? I can imagine how to calculate the probability of each number being picked here, but I was wondering if this had a name or if anyone had formalized it (My GoogleFu is failing me). I mentioned the discrete case as it's relevant to the problem I'm trying to solve, but I'm curious about the continuous case as well.

Comment: Given $X_1, X_2 \sim$ Uniform and iid , $X_1 +X_2 \sim$ triangular distribution:

Comment: Although the duplicate deals explicitly with the case $N=2,$ all larger $N$ are also addressed for the simple reason that any sum of $N\gt 2$ values can be written (in many ways) as the sum of two sub-sums.